# GDB command to access a particular element in linked list?

Tags: gdb

Is there any command in GDB to directly find out the value of a particular element(say 20th) in a linked list?

Answer (score 4):

You can make an appropriate user-defined function (in gdb).  For example, suppose that you get to the next element in your linked list by accessing `->next`, we can create a function `xyzzy` as follows (from gdb's prompt):

```
define xyzzy
  set $current = $arg0
  set $ii = $arg1
    while ($ii > 0)
      set $ii = $ii - 1
      set $current = $current->next
    end
  print (something appropriate with $current)
  end
```

You have then created a function which takes two arguments.  The first is an element in your linked list and the second is the number of `->next`s that you are to follow.  You'll need to put something appropriate in the print line.